# Not able to render a collection in an Marionette ItemView

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I have some problems to render a collection wihin an `ItemView`. Form Marionette doc ([Rendering A Collection In An ItemView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#rendering-a-collection-in-an-itemview)) there is written that I can pass a collection to an `ItemView` and within my template I can just iterate over `items` like so.

```
<script id="some-template" type="text/html">
  <ul>
    <% _.each(items, function(item){ %>
    <li> <%= item.someAttribute %> </li>
    <% }); %>
  </ul>
</script>
```

But in my case it seems not working.

This is the code I'm using.

```
var report1 = new ReportModel({ name: "David", report:"1" });
var report2 = new ReportModel({ name: "Mark", report:"2" });
var report3 = new ReportModel({ name: "Jack",  report:"3" });

var reportCollection = new ReportCollection( [report1, report2, report3] );

// create the view and inject somewhere, code skipped for brevity here
new CollectView( { model: reportModel, collection: reportCollection } );
```

The template is enriched by means of Handlebars like so.

```
{{log items}}

{{#each items}}
<div data-role="drop-class"><span>{{this.name}}</span></div>
{{/each}}
```

If I log `items`, `undefined` is displayed.

The model of the view is used to display other data. My requirements: I need to have an `ItemView`. No `Collection` or `CompositeView`.

Any advice?

Comment: Why do you need an ItemView instead of a CollectionView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass *both* a model and a collection to an `ItemView`, the `items` array is not set in the [`serializeData` method](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/src/marionette.itemview.js#L15-L32) called before rendering the view. That's why `items` is `undefined`.

To make `items` available in this case it would be necessary to override the `serializeData` method appropriately.

(See also the [answer for this same issue in Marionette's GitHub](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/1334).)

Answer (score 0):

The View doesnt need to know the model and the collection.

Try :

```
// create the view and inject somewhere, code skipped for brevity here
new CollectView( { collection: reportCollection } );
```